# Xml file show incorrect time data after exported it from gridview

Tags: c#, xml, gridview, time, writexml

I have a gridview which display some information. One of those information is a time data like: 19:40:00.0000000. When I tried to export my gridview to xml file using WriteXml I found incorrect data for my time, it is look like : PT7H50M .

--> My time data : 19:40:00.0000000  in gridview converted to :  PT7H50M  after export it to xml file Why and How can I solve this problem ?

this is a time data in my gridview : 
[image: My time data in gridview]

This is what it look like in xml file :

[image]

This is the code of export :

DataTable Rdt = new DataTable();
                        DataSet Rds = new DataSet();

```
                    Rdt = (DataTable)GV_Report.DataSource;
                    Rds.Tables.Add(Rdt.Copy());

                    Rds.WriteXml(@"c:\Reporting\Work_Hours_Report.xml", System.Data.XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema);

                    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
                    settings.Indent = true;
                    XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(@"c:\Reporting\ReportType.xml", settings);
                    writer.WriteStartDocument();
                    writer.WriteComment("This file is generated by the program...Please do not change this file!!");
                    writer.WriteStartElement("ReportBut");
                    writer.WriteElementString("ButType", "Work_Hours_Report");
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                    writer.WriteEndDocument();
                    writer.Flush();
                    writer.Close();
```

I tried to edit my SQL statement by adding Aliases to each selected columns but unfortunately it does not make any improvement :

```
select CAST(DATEADD(MILLISECOND,SUM(DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,0,CAST(ISNULL([Total_H],'00:00:00') AS DATETIME))),0) AS TIME) as '1',sum([HTotal]) as '2',sum([MTotal]) as '3',CAST(DATEADD(MILLISECOND,SUM(DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,0,CAST(ISNULL([PH_Total],'00:00:00') AS DATETIME))),0) AS TIME) as '4',sum([PH]) as '5',sum([PM]) as '6',CAST(DATEADD(MILLISECOND,SUM(DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,0,CAST(ISNULL([AH_Total],'00:00:00') AS DATETIME))),0) AS TIME) as '7',sum([AH]) as '8',sum([AM]) as '9'  FROM [QAMNI].[dbo].[tbl_WorkHours_Details]  where [Date] between '" + DF + "' and '" + DT + "' and [C_ID] ='" + txt_C_ID.Text + "'
```

Comment: Could you add your code to the question? This way other users will be able to analyse it and help you.

Comment: Just to rule out the obvious.. what's the header of that column where the 19:40:00 is showing? Also, change your `XmlWriteMode` to `WriteSchema`, it might give you (and us) some clues.

Comment: My gridview is hidden from user interface the header of that column is unnamed by default it was named as Column1 by MVS...!!

Comment: Yeah, I thought so. The value of that column based on what I can see there is probably '06/09/2015 19:40:00'. Your grid view is showing the time, but the export is showing the date. As for the 'PT..' value, that's not coming from that column at all.

Comment: Please wait I will try to name all my selected SQL statement using Aliases. Hope this solve my problem.

Comment: Are you in Pacific Time Zone (PT)?  It looks like the code is assuming the textbox is in UTC and converting the time to the timezone setting in your computer.

Comment: @ Flynn1179: unfortunately it does not make any improvement

Comment: Side note: "P" is prefix for duration (http://www.datypic.com/sc/xsd/t-xsd_dayTimeDuration.html) - this may hint to what actually get serialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the advance of Mr. @**Flynn1179**

I changed the XmlWriteMode from IgnoreSchema to WriteSchema and the result was correct without any xsd: dayTimeDuration represents duration of time expressed as a number of days, hours, minutes, and seconds. The format of xsd: dayTimeDuration is PnDTnHnMnS as in my Reporting file, once I change it I got the time exactly as I select from my database without any change in format. Thank you all of you for help.
This is my XML file after changing the XmlWriteMode from IgnoreSchema to WriteSchema :

[image]

It still display as xsd format but when I print it out to end user using crystal report it give me correct time format as (“hh:mm:ss”) :

[image]

This is what I change in my code:(only changing the XmlWriteMode)

```
 Rds.WriteXml(@"c:\Reporting\WorkHours_Report.xml", System.Data.XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```